# Conversion operator overloading

Tags: c++, overloading, function-templates, conversion-operator

I want to distinguish a template conversion operator between &, * and values:

```
struct S
{
    template <class T>
    constexpr operator T()
    {
        return value;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr operator T&()
    {
        return value;
    }
    template <class T>
    constexpr operator T*()
    {
        return &value;
    }
    int value;
} s{5};

int main()
{
    uint32_t ui = s; // error:  error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'S' to 'uint32_t
}
```

If I remove `constexpr operator T&()` the code compiles and `ui = s` invokes the `constexpr operator T()` operator. But why?

I also get strange behaviour when I add the explicit specifier to those funcitons.

It looks like the behaviour of the conversion operator differs from normal overloading. May anyone explain this?

PS: I'm using VS2017

Comment: Was that intended as a language lawyer question? The code is mostly nonsensical, suggest a theoretical C++ question and not a practical question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `value` is of type `int`, it does not make sense to create a template conversion to a template parameter reference type. If the type is not `int`, you have a semantic error of trying to coerce an `int` object to a reference of some other type.

Redefine the reference conversion to the proper types:

```
constexpr operator int&()
{
    return value;
}
constexpr operator const int&() const
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: Need both for `const int` and `int`.

Comment: https://tio.run/##pY/BCsIwDIbvfYqAMFTQg@JpupfY7lJq1EHXlTYVZfTZa9fqSQaKOTV/83/5I7ReXYQIs1YJ6U4I@1YRPTTa9bUKlowTBDUbGMQi7LTkFIeE5NZCUyVZ9MoS3rWBXqPh1Bto5ov0lX1jGSRnFNy4dFgm1U@ZY4LiH3@SXpTcfMn64b7lVMDigxqDvFd5sMPOl4yNWsdbFSmZ4KKy3RwpPuAANvtrKAyec@9DeAI

Comment: Oh yes, I see. Thank you. But my example was obviously not precise enougth. I want convert into references without a int constructor. So I defently want to return a type of type T not int.

Comment: I want do something totally different in the & - part. I have to distinguish between T& and T.

Comment: How about you try writing a new question explaining the behavior you want, the code you tried to achieve it, and what about your attempt didn't work? I think I have addressed this particular question.